# Fast render animation?

Tags: animation, blender-internal-render-engine

Hi I should make a video for a project of a hydroponic containers but the rendering time is over 30 hours ... how can I reduce it while maintaining good graphics ? Thanks !

Comment: Render without textures. That will reduce the time.You can also reduce fps, if it won't affect appearance of the final animation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a first you need to know what is your priority: time or quality? You can't have both.

This is very complex "problem" and need a lot of study. What is good in one situation may not be good in another. 
Generally:

In "**Sampling**":

- set Clamp to higher value
- use "Branched Path Tracing" - check noise in every pass in compositor and adjust Samples by render pass.

In "**Light Paths**":

- turn off caustic.
- reduce light bounces.

In "**Performance**":

- set Tilles according to your hardware (usually 64x64 for CPU, 256x256 for GPU).
- tick "Persistent images" if your textures does not change in full length of animation
- try using "Spatial Splits".

In Material **node editor:**
Use "Light path" for determine rays you don't need. For example disable shadow ray in glass can speed up render quite a lot.

I mentioned only most used features. There is not a general "golden rule" that work always and in every case. All settings depend of your scene and your preferences.

BTW: render animation about 30 hours is not unusual.

Comment: PS: one user here wrote very smart adage: There are quality, time and money. You can have two of them. My answer is about ratio between quality and time. If we add money, you can buy better HW or pay for render farm. There are no other way, because of technology limits and physical laws.

Comment: I have to second the 30 hours not being unusual.  I have had projects 5-6 minutes long take ~125 hours to render, and that's not even in Cycles!  I will also mention that for render farms, Sheep It is a free one that is community based, so the more your render other's projects, the higher priority your project has in the render queue (I've had 24x speedup on some projects, but of course it varies).

Answer (score 0):

I found that setting the render style under **Render -> Performance -> Tiles** to **Left to Right** instead of **Center** cut my render time to 25 mins a frame, whereas before i was getting about 45-50 mins a frame for animation. I was also rendering at 720 by 1920 pixels, mainly because i was doing an animation test with only one character in frame at a time.
[image: These are the settings I used.]

EDIT: Duarte Farrajota Ramos pointed out that only changing one setting shouldn't have such a large affect on the render time. When i looked through my settings and files that i had before and after the decreased amount of time, i realized that i had rendered still images of the animation before the final animated version was rendered, and had **Persistant Images** enabled.

Comment: Those are bold claims, are you sure you didn't change any other settings? I strongly doubt just changing tile direction would reduce render times by a magnitude of 50%